# Incorrect expected output in jump game leetcode problem

Tags: data-structures

I was doing data structure practice on leetcode.

Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/

For this question, when I submitted my solution it failed for input

```
[2,5,0,0]
```

Leetcode expects the output to be true but I can't follow why it should be true. Can somone explain me the question?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the explanation based on your input, `[2,5,0,0]`. Here the value at `i`th index/position represents the **maximum jumps** you can take from the `i`th index/position. So the input will be interpreted in the following way,

```
Index/position       value                      What this means?
    0                  2       You can take maximum 2 jumps from index 0 i.e. you can reach index 1 and 2 from index 0 [0 --(1st jump)--> 1 --(2nd jump)--> 2]
    1                  5       You can take maximum 5 jumps from index 1 i.e. you can reach index 2 and 3 (array ends at index 3) from index 1 [1 --(1st jump)--> 2 --(2nd jump)--> 3]
    2                  0       You cannot jump to any other index from index 2.
    3                  0       You cannot jump to any other index from index 3 (the array ends here anyway).
```

*Focus on the **maximum jumps** part because you may chose to take fewer number of jumps to reach the last index.* Now I hope the question is clear to you, lets look at the solution i.e. why the expected answer is `true`?

`[2,5,0,0]` - here the goal is to reach index 3 from index 0.
You have to make sure that you don't end up at index 2 because you cannot take any jump from index 2 i.e. you cannot reach last index 3 from index 2. So, you have to first take 1 jump from index 0 (you can take maximum 2 jumps from index 0) to reach index 1, and then take 2 jumps from index 1 (you can take maximum 5 jumps from index 0) to reach the last index 3.

Comment: I don't think I understand the logic here. Each element is saying how many steps how you can jump when you are on i=0, you can max go to i=2 which happens to be "0" which and not the last element, so this should have return false.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused here "represents your maximum jump length at that position".

```
Input: nums = [2, 5, 0, 0]
```

Output: true

Explanation: Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 2 steps to the last index.

Here the jump length at each index is at most the value of the index.

Comment: Appreciate you answering the question but I can't follow your answer. Can you please write the input of the example you used in your answer and the one with `[2,5,0,0]`